# right way to set a Path to readonly in java.nio2

Tags: java, nio2

I'm confused... according to [this Java page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html) the [`File.setReadOnly()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadOnly()) function is now a "legacy" function and should be replaced by [`Files.setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...))... but this requires you to know whether you are working with a DOS or a POSIX filesystem. I just want to make a file read-only, in a platform-independent manner. How should I do it?

Answer (score 11):

I believe Oracle is only calling them "legacy" in light of the new *java.nio.file* API. If they truly wanted to discourage its usage they would have deprecated those methods.

But if you would still like to use NIO2, say for the sake of consistency, you can query the platform's underlying `FileStore` for *DOS* or *POSIX* attributes support.

```
Path file = Paths.get("file.txt");

// Files.createFile(file);
System.out.println(Files.isWritable(file)); // true

// Query file system
FileStore fileStore = Files.getFileStore(file);
if (fileStore.supportsFileAttributeView(DosFileAttributeView.class)) {
    // Set read-only
    Files.setAttribute(file, "dos:readonly", true);
} else if (fileStore.supportsFileAttributeView(PosixFileAttributeView.class)) {
    // Change permissions
}
System.out.println(Files.isWritable(file)); // false
```

There are also `FileAttributeView` classes that you can use to update multiple attributes easily.

```
DosFileAttributeView attrs =
            Files.getFileAttributeView(
                        file, DosFileAttributeView.class);
attrs.setSystem(true);
attrs.setHidden(true);
attrs.setReadOnly(true);
```

Comment: Do you happen to know where attributes such as `dos:readonly` are documented?

Comment: Ah, I found them in [`java.nio.file.attribute.DosFileAttributeView`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/attribute/DosFileAttributeView.html).

Comment: Note that using `FileStore.supportsFileAttributeView(…)` may not give the correct result for non-local file systems; see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74351123) to my question, [_Type guarantees for getting DOS file attributes in Java_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73141485).